# Split string on comma when field contains a comma

Tags: python, string, list, split

Consider the following string:

```
'538.48,0.29,"533.59 - 540.00","AZO",102482,"+0.05%","N/A",0.00,535.09,"AutoZone, Inc. Co",538.77,"N/A"'
```

I need to split this into a list so it looks like the following:

```
[538.48, 0.29, "533.59 - 540.00", "AZO", 102482, "+0.05%" , "N/A", 0.00, 535.09, "AutoZone, Inc. Co", 538.77, "N/A"]
```

The problem is I can't use `list.split(',')` because the 10th field has a comma within it. The question is then how best to split the original string into a list when arbitrary fields may have a comma?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) rather than attempt to split this yourself, it handles quoted values, including quoted values containing the delimiter, out of the box:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> data = '538.48,0.29,"533.59 - 540.00","AZO",102482,"+0.05%","N/A",0.00,535.09,"AutoZone, Inc. Co",538.77,"N/A"'
>>> reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines())
>>> pprint(next(reader))
['538.48',
 '0.29',
 '533.59 - 540.00',
 'AZO',
 '102482',
 '+0.05%',
 'N/A',
 '0.00',
 '535.09',
 'AutoZone, Inc. Co',
 '538.77',
 'N/A']
```

Note the `'AutoZone, Inc. Co'` column value.

If you are reading this data from a file, pass in the file object to the `csv.reader()` object directly rather than hand it sequences of strings.

You can even have the numeric values (anything not quoted) interpreted as floating point values, by setting [`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC):

```
>>> reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
>>> pprint(next(reader))
[538.48,
 0.29,
 '533.59 - 540.00',
 'AZO',
 102482.0,
 '+0.05%',
 'N/A',
 0.0,
 535.09,
 'AutoZone, Inc. Co',
 538.77,
 'N/A']
```

Comment: This is converting the floats to strings. The floats need to be retained within the list elements.

Comment: @strimp099: you *started with a string*, not with floating point numbers. You can set the the reader to interpret all non-quoted values as numeric with [`QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC), at which point they'll be converted to floats for you.

Comment: I appreciate the initial line is a string but the output in the OP has the numeric values as numeric, not strings. Also, using `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` does not appear to unquote the numeric values.

Comment: @strimp099: what do you mean by 'unquote the numeric values'?

Comment: What I meant was that the numeric values where still being quoted. However, I just wasn't using the `quoting` keyword, rather just passing the constant to the `reader` method. Appears to be working now, thank you.